# Determine class type from a reference like #<Class:0x007fdf62060e48>

Tags: ruby

When I develop in Rails sometimes a NoMethodError will appear:

```
(undefined method `new_with_url' for #<Class:0x007fdf62060e48>):
```

I am wondering if I can determine the class which is raising the value based on the string `Class:0x007fdf62060e48`. I can't easily reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Ruby (MRI) 1.9.3, but is very implementation-dependent and may change at any time:

```
ObjectSpace._id2ref(0x007fdf62060e48 / 2)
```

This operates on the assumption that the hex number in the description `#<Class:0x007fdf62060e48>` is two times the object's actual ID, which indeed (AFAIK) is true of all objects besides Fixnums in MRI. I'm not sure you'll be able to get anything useful out of the output, though; the class still has no name, so it'd be very tricky to find it in your code.